# DestroyJavaVM only thread left

Tags: java, eclipse

I am testing an application in Eclipse with debugging, using a main method, and the application does not terminate.

When I look at the debug profile, it seems that Thread DestroyJavaVM is the only thread left.  Are there any ideas how I can determine why the app is not stopping?

```
MyApp[Java Application] 
    com.myapp.testing.MyTest at localhost:63807 
        Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)    
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe (Jun 30, 2014, 5:50:05 PM)
```

EDIT: If I run my app's main method from the command line it also hangs and does not finish.  So obviously I have some bad code.

Therefore I have two questions:

1)  Why does Eclipse only show the DestryJavaVM Thread?
2)  What are some approaches to determine what is causing this app never to terminate?

Comment: Dear SO-user, please write a comment, why you vote a question down. Otherwise a new member would never learn, what was wrong with th queestion.

Comment: Did you find the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a flag "Keep JVM running" activated?

This would keep one Thread until you stop debugging.

Comment: Is Keep JVM Running an Eclipse option?  I don't see this in Debug configurations.  This issue also occurs when running the app without debugging in Eclipse.